# Reject edits with just added tags

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have rejected some edits by @RoninEngineer.

To add RPI-4 tags to a question that is a generic question and NOT specific for Raspberry Pi 4 is not an edit that enhance the question in my opinion.

Advice? Yes/no?

Answer (score 5):

Unless the question is specifically about the Pi 4 as described by the tag:

```
For questions that apply specifically to the Raspberry Pi 4 and not other/all models.
```

There is no reason to add the tag.

As an aside I'm not really a fan of edits that just change the tags. There's normally some aspect of formatting and/or grammar that can also be improved at the same time. (Sometimes changing the tags is enough of an improvement in itself but I would say that this is not common).

Comment: Thx that was my opinion to.

Comment: I agree WRT the misuse of 'p-4' but, WRT just adding a tag, if it is an improvement, doing something is better than doing nothing because too much needs to be done and you don't have time for all of it.

Comment: I'm not a fan of edits that just change spelling and/or grammar. Often these are to ancient posts, add NOTHING to understanding and just push the question into the Activity queue, encouraging unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 3):

Adding unnecessary tags is vandalism. Just because the OP is using a Pi4 doesn't make it a Pi4 question.

Similar applies to tags like `python-3` for generic python questions (which are usually deleted on Stack Overflow).

Some tags e.g. `raspbian` are MEANINGLESS (unless they apply to Wheezy) and benefit from a change, as they make tag searches more useful.

Comment: Vandalism is an intentional act that is deliberately destructive. An edit which makes the question worse is a deterioration.